# Transaction synchronization vs transaction association in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, persistence

I don't understand the difference between the concepts. Pro JPA 2 says the following:

> Transaction synchronization is the process by which a persistence context is registered with a transaction so that the persistence context can be notified when a transaction commits. The provider uses this notification to ensure that a given persistence context is correctly flushed to the database.
>
> Transaction association is the act of binding a persistence context to a transaction. You can also think of this as the active persistence
> context within the scope of that transaction.

Could you please give some more explanation, maybe practical examples? Should I care about it in Java SE environment not using any JTA transactions? Thank you for any note!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transaction Synchronization : You can think of this as Spring's TransactionSynchronization interface which receives callback for transaction synchronization..It has various methods like `afterCommit()`, `afterCompletion()`,`beforeCommit()` which get called as per transaction's state..Consider a practical example where you want to send an email to user once user registration is completed ,notify any external service depending on transaction state or log any particular event..

Transaction association:we basically commit transaction under active persistence context..let it be JPA's Entity manager or Hibernate's session..

Should I care about it in Java SE environment not using any JTA transactions?Yes..you will have to fall back to JDBC transaction demarcation..